# MySQL General log not working on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql-5.5, mac-os-x, log

I want to log all queries to the database running on my MacBook Pro (Mac OS X 10.8.1). I created a file `/etc/my.cnf` with the following content:

```
[mysqld]
general_log=1
general_log_file=/Users/wdb/mysql.log
```

I restarted MySQL and tried some queries on the mysql command line, but nothing gets logged. The file is not getting created. I also created the file myself afterwards to test with `touch`, but the file remains empty.

When I check, MySQL did read my settings:

```
mysql> show variables like '%general_log%';
+------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                |
+------------------+----------------------+
| general_log      | ON                   |
| general_log_file | /Users/wdb/mysql.log |
+------------------+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Is there anything else I need to do? I suppose any query I type on the command line should get logged, right?

I am using MySQL 5.5.24

Comment: The file is probably not writable by the MySQL user. Check the permissions, plus the permissions of the directory it resides in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is indeed as @Phil hinted at. To fix it, set the permissions for the `_mysql` user:

```
> cd ~
> touch mysql.log
> sudo chown _mysql:wheel mysql.log
```

Restart MySQL after that and the log file will be used.